# laravel authentication using ajax, validation

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using laravel's defult auth system but I'm sending requests threw ajax. If I am for example on login page and I send some wrong data, it throws me an error into console:

```
POST http://some.app/auth/login/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

but actually it returns some data:

```
email: ["The email must be a valid email address."]
```

Same weird acting for registration.

**1.** how to fix those status codes?

**2.** how to handle those errors? Just writing data.email and data.password to an user? Isn't there a better solution?

**3.** what about csrf token? I'm sending it with data but it doesn't seem to require that

Thanks

Comment: Laravel returning 422 seems to be intentional. See here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#controller-validation it says "If the incoming request was an AJAX request, no redirect will be generated. Instead, an HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the browser containing a JSON representation of the validation errors.". So in your ajax call, you can define the error callback function to handle the errors, and the success callback function for when authentication succeeds.

Comment: oh thanks, but that status code is making an error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a validation error.

The information is returned to the `$errors` variable. You can handle that any way you want but I guess the most obvious action would be to show the error to the user.

Actually it's better to have a 422 than a 200 (everything OK, for it's not). Since the auth system relies on the validation request, you wouldn't want the controller to proceed (eg by saving data that didn't pass validation).